# How should a fragment communicate with another class in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, surfaceview

I am currently building a camera app and have a problem:
I have got a fragment that should contain a camerapreview. Now this camerapreview is a custom implementation as it extends `SurfaceView`.

Now my actual question is, how should my custom camerapreview talk to the fragment? For instance, I would like to be able to let my fragment know, that a touch event occured.

What approach should i use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. If you don't need this to be reusable, then a solution with a higher amount of coupling is ok. In which case the fragment tells the view about itself and the view can just call a method:

```
class CustomCameraPreview extends SurfaceView
{
  FragmentA fragment;
  // Call from onCreateView() in the framgnet
  public void setFragment(FragmentA fragment)
  {
    this.fragment = fragment;
  }

  private void someMethod() {
    if ( fragment != null)
      fragment.callback();

  }

}

public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

  public void callback() {
    // called from the view
  }
}
```

If you need this to be more generic and reusable, then create a interface that contains the kind of callbacks the view would need to call and have the fragment implement that interface. This is basically the Observer pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

```
interface CameraPreviewListener {

   public void callback1() ;
   public void callback2() ;

}

class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView 
{
  CameraPreviewListener listener;
  // Call from onCreateView() in the framgnet
  public void setFragment(CameraPreviewListener listener)
  {
    this.listener = listener;
  }

  private void someMethod1() {
    if ( listener != null)
      listener.callback1();    
  }

  private void someMethod2() {
    if ( listener != null)
      listener.callback2();    
  }

}

public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements CameraPreviewListener{

  public void callback1() {
    // called from the view
  }

  public void callback2() {
    // called from the view
  }
}
```

Comment: great, really like the approach with the callbacks!

Answer (score 1):

`Fragment` object got field `CameraPreview` so it should be easy to inform your fragment class back if you make your CameraPreview inner class.

If you dont want to make CustomCameraPreview class inner, make your fragment implement `MyOnClickListener` and then pass to your cameraPreview object this listener. And if some event occurs inform listener with suitable method

```
class CustomCameraPreview extends SurfaceView
{
  MyOnClickListener listener;
  // some stuff
  public void setListneer(MyOnClickListener listener)
  {
    this.listener = listener;
  }

  //// if someone touch something
  if(listener!=null)
  {
    listener.somethingWasTouched();
  }
}

interface MyOnClickListener 
{
  public void somethingWasTouched();
}

class MyFragment extends Fragment implements MyOnClickListener 
{
    @Override
    public void somethingWasTouched()
    {
     //info that something was touched / profit
    }
}
```